# Long article titles on my Careers 2.0 profile while in Edit mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On my Careers 2.0 profile I have some long titles under Articles & Blogs. A portion of these titles are bleeding into the Edit link beside the title while in edit mode.